# My nav bar is downloading files but only on github

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, navbar

Just so yall know I did search around for a answer and could not find one.

So I am making a website for my schools robotics team. Cyrusmusic101.github.io is where you can view the site.

When loaded up in my browser off my computer it works or when on my phone it works, but on laptops or computers when I click the explore button it downloads the info.html on github. Is it because of my code or a github issue?

Code for the a href to link it over to the next doc.

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1>Chs Robotics</h1>
        <a href="info.index" class="btn">Explore</a>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
        <p class="ftm">© CHS Robotics: Developed by CyrusMusic101.</p>
        </div>

   </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name your html files with a `.html` extension, then change your links to:

```
<a href="info.html" class="btn">Explore</a>
```

The reason the browser is trying to download the page instead of browsing to it is because it doesn't recognize the file type as being one it can open, such as `.htm`, `.html`, `.jpg`, etc.

If you're wondering why some sites have URLs that don't have `.html` at the end, that's because they're using a web server which is setting the header of the response to the browser, telling it to treat whatever is sent back as HTML. Without the header (like on github pages), the browser has to guess what type of file it is using the file name extension.

Comment: Thank you I didn't notice that I had index instead of html how dumb of me.

Comment: @CyrusMusic101 great, don't forget to upvote and mark this question correct.